# C++ What is more efficient: defining a sum with a loop or unraveled with Horner's method?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++, and I have a sum of terms to implement as a function. More to the point, [see this](http://www.d-filter.ece.uvic.ca/SupMaterials/Slides/DSP-Ch10-S1-7.pdf), slide 115, the formula for `Ωi`.

What I'd like to know is how efficient would it be to implement it (this is valid for `σ0`, on slide 114, too): with a loop that iterates through each terms of the nominator and denominator, or with a readily expanded and factored with Horner's method version?

I know that the latter will have the downside of being fixed, and it will need rewriting everytime a change is needed, but that may well be something done only in the beginning, while "calibrating". My guess would be the 2nd method would be faster, but if it's not by much, then I'd rather have the 1st version, since it will be more readable. Still, I'd like to hear what experience has to say.

Comment: there is no magic way to find it out other than implementing both ways and measure. I would never trust experience when it is about efficient code

Comment: @tobi303 I am currently learning C++ and classes is the farthest I am in. I don't know how to measure this, that's why I thought maybe there are similar cases other people went through and can give some hints.

Comment: the most important rule of optimization is: Dont do it. (there is a trustworthy reference, but I dont remember atm). The point is: the time you have to write (and rewrite) your code is a significant amount of time, thus you should first care about writing something with priority on nice and easy to understand code. Once you get results and you really need it faster only then you can start considering to optimize, but it does not make much sense to waste time on thinking how you might get 10% speedup before having any code.

Comment: @tobi303 That's a good point. Then I'll make it with a for loop for better readability and continue with it. Maybe later on, when I learn how to measure these, I can make tests and see for myself. By then I would know beforehand how many terms I will actually need. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson) you can find the quote with a proper reference. It was from MIchael Jackson (not the singing one)